# Função Ajax sendo ignorada

Tags: javascript, ajax

Galera, eu tenho esse código que estou usando para buscar as validações do servidor e exibir no plugin de validação do jquery que utilizo.

```
function nomeExiste(value, validator, $field) {                         
    var retorno;            
    $.ajax({
        url: '/saboia/funcionarios/'+$field.val()+'/validaNovo/',
        method: 'PUT',                              
        success: function(e){   
            console.log(e);
            retorno = e;           
        }
    });                                                     

    if (!retorno) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

O retorno dessa função vem lá do servidor e é um booleano, porém, quando eu executo essa função ela entra diretamente nos if's e acaba que a atribuição do retorno dentro do ajax é "ignorado", porque isso acontece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `retorno` ainda é `undefined` quando passa pelo `if`.
Isso porque o script não espera a requisição Ajax terminar para dar continuidade.

Você precisa colocar um função callback para ser chamado assim que a requisição terminar, e partir daí continuar com seu script.

```
function nomeExiste(value, validator, $field, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/saboia/funcionarios/' + $field.val() + '/validaNovo/',
        method: 'PUT',
        success: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            callback(e);
        }
    });
}

nomeExiste("value", "validator", "$field", function(e) {
    if (e) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Opa rafa, obrigado pela resposta, vou testar aqui e te dou o retorno ok? E feliz natal!